# How can I block all ports except 22,80,443 to all incoming traffic except localhost?

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, iptables, port

I want this behaviour:

All outside computers can only bind to my server's ports 22(ssh), 80(http) and 443(https).

However all localhost apps can bind to any port they want.

I have search and this is what I came up with:

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport ! --dports 22,80,443 -j DROP`

It does what I want, but blocks to all localhost apps as well. What should I change there to enable localhost apps bind to any port?

And then how can I make the rule permanent?

Thanks!

Comment: been a while but what if you add `-s 127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: won't that just apply this rule to localhost connections? i.e. only localhost connections will get blocked on all ports but those 3?

Comment: I guess I meant it more in the way like timmy did it. on an accept line.

Answer (score 1):

Rules are matched in order.  Make one to allow for localhost ahead of the one to deny.

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s localhost -m tcp -m multiport ! --dports 22,80,443 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -m multiport ! --dports 22,80,443 -j DROP

Read here for how to save them depending on your OS.  https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Saving_Iptables_Firewall_Rules_Permanently